# Erasing application cache in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, caching

I wrote a WPF app that makes some changes to registry involving write blocking USB. Everything works fine, and I have set up a button to test the write protection by creating a text file and attempting to save it to a USB drive when one is plugged in.

I've encountered a bug where sometimes if I turn write protection on, check it with my test button that attempts to save a file, then disable write blocking, when I try to write the file to the USB it still gives me a write protection error. I've confirmed its no longer protected in registry, and I turn it off before inserting the USB. The only way to fix this bug is to just restart the app.

So I'm wondering is there any command I can use to basically just give the app a quick reset after hitting this test button (hopefully without restarting it)? Not sure how the app is doing caching but it must be saving something for this bug to be happening.

This is the code to create the registry subkey and save the value.

```
private void WriteBlockOn_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies", true);
            key.SetValue("WriteProtect", 1);
            key.Close();
            ProtectStatus.Foreground = Brushes.LawnGreen;
            ProtectStatus.Text = "Write Protection is ON";
            MessageBox.Show("Changes applied to registry. Always test functionality using a test USB drive before connecting your evidence drive.");
        }
```

And this is the test button code to save a file.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create OpenFileDialog 
        SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        {
            // Set filter for file extension and default file extension 
            dialog.FileName = "WriteBlockTest.txt";
            dialog.DefaultExt = "=.txt";
            dialog.Title = "This a test of your write blocker";
            dialog.Filter = "This is a write blocking test(*.txt)|*.txt";
        };

        // Display OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method 
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            try
            {
                // create a writer and open the file
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(dialog.FileName);
                // write a line of text to the file
                tw.WriteLine("Write Block Test");
                // close the stream
                tw.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot Write to Drive. Drive is Write Protected.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Sure, added to main post

Comment: Try to put `new StreamWriter` inside `using`, it's likely failing because file handle is not released so second and following up calls can't open the file, rather than not being able to write to it. Btw, `catch(Exception)` is a bad idea, you are swallowing exceptions without seeing what exact problem you have. Never do it.

Comment: If I don't catch the exception though I get a UE crash when it hits the write protection error.